# Enquiry about the input & output shape of LSTMs in Keras

Tags: keras, lstm

I am trying to predict a time series with LSTM and am writing my code in Python by using Keras.

I have 30 features as input (continuous value) and a binary output.

I would like to use the 20 previous timesteps (t-20, t-19, .. , t-1) of each input feature in order to predict the output of next timestep (t+1).

My batch size is fixed at 52. What does this exactly mean?

I don't understand how to define the shape of the input layer.

The stacked LSTM example in the Keras documentation says that the last dimension of the 3D tensor will be 'data_dim'.

Is it input dimension or output dimension?

If this is output dimension, then I can't use more than one input feature as in my case the input_shape will be `(batch_size=52,time_step=20,data_dim=1)`.

Also, in case `data_dim` is input shape, then I have tried to define a four layers-LSTM and the model shape results to be like this.

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
================================================================= input_2 (InputLayer)         (52, 20, 30)              0         
_________________________________________________________________ lstm_3 (LSTM)                (52, 20, 128)             81408     
_________________________________________________________________ lstm_4 (LSTM)                (52, 128)                 131584    
_________________________________________________________________ dense_2 (Dense)              (52, 1)                   129       
================================================================= Total params: 213,121 Trainable params: 213,121 Non-trainable params: 0
```

Does this architecture make sense? Am I making some obvious mistakes?

My snippet of code is the one below:

```
input_layer=Input(batch_shape=(batch_size,input_timesteps,input_dims))
lstm1=LSTM(num_neurons,activation = 'relu',dropout=0.0,stateful=False,return_sequences=True)(input_layer)
lstm2=LSTM(num_neurons,activation = 'relu',dropout=0.0,stateful=False,return_sequences=False)(lstm1)
output_layer=Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(lstm2)
model=Model(inputs=input_layer,outputs=output_layer)
```

I am getting very poor results and thus trying to debug each step.

Comment: Are you able to overfit the model with the training data? Like by increasing the hidden units.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use deep learning techniques you should try to overfit first and then reduce the complexity till you reach a break even point in terms of both neural complexity, training error and test error.

You are actually using a larger feature space in the hidden layer, are you sure your data are able to fit this?
Do you have enough rows to let the model learn this complex representation?
Otherwise I would suggest you something like this, in order to extrapolate the most important dimensions:

```
num_neurons1 = int(input_dims/2)
num_neurons2 = int(input_dims/4)
input_layer=Input(batch_shape=(batch_size, input_timesteps, input_dims))
lstm1=LSTM(num_neurons, activation = 'relu', dropout=0.0, stateful=False, return_sequences=True, kernel_initializer="he_normal")(input_layer)
lstm2=LSTM(num_neurons2, activation = 'relu', dropout=0.0, stateful=False, return_sequences=False, kernel_initializer="he_normal")(lstm1)
output_layer=Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(lstm2)
model=Model(inputs=input_layer,outputs=output_layer)
```

Also, you are using relu as activation function.
Does it fit your data? Would be better you have only positive data after rescaling & normalization.
In case it does fit, you can also use a proper kernel initialization.
To better understand the problem, you could also post the optimizer parameters and the behaviour while training during epochs.